# $x\in F(x)$ is transcedental over $F$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

We want to show that $x\in F(x)$ is transcedental over $F$, where $F(x)$ is the field of franctions of $F[x]$.

**Answer:** We suppose contrary that $x\in F(x)$ is algebraic over $F$. And this happens if and only if $F[x]=F(x)$.  So, $F[x]$ is the polynomial ring over $F$ with intermediate the element $x$ and it's not a field, but $F(x)$ is a field. Contradiction.

Is this thought right? And is there another way?

*Thank you in advance.*

Comment: One issue: you cannot claim that $x$ is algebraic if and only if $F[x]=F(x)$. This needs some serious explanation (and it may not even be true).

Comment: @Andrew Thank you for your comment. Why? We know that if 
$$a\in E \text{ is algebraic over F } \iff F[a]=F(a)$$

Comment: I've never seen this result before. Can you provide a reference for it?

Comment: I think your approach is correct.

Comment: Sure you have seen this. Maybe I misunderstand something. Look: If we have the fields extension $E:F$, and $a\in E$, we have this above and $F[a]$ is a field. Do you want still reference?

Comment: I see, I think you're right. I've never seen it phrased this way before.

Comment: What was uncommon?

Comment: By the way you should have observed that by definition the indeterminate $x$ is transcendental over the field $F$. It is only on the basis of the fact that $x$ is indeterminate the ring $F[x] $ has infinite dimension as a vector space over $F$. So this alone shows that $x$ is transcendental over $F$.

Comment: The need to consider field $F(x) $ is because the concept of algebraic / transcendental is always for members of a field extension $E$ of $F$. So we need to have a field extension of $F$ which contains $x$ and $F(x) $ is one such field.